# Let $K_n$ is a nonempty compact subset of $X$ and that $K_{n+1} \subset K_n$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$. Show that $f(K) = \bigcap _n f(K_n)$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous map between metric spaces. Assume that $K_n$ is a nonempty compact subset of $X$ and that $K_{n+1} \subset K_n$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$. Let $K := \bigcap _n K_n$. Show that $f(K) = \bigcap _n f(K_n)$.

I have done in the following way:

$\Rightarrow$
If $x \in K$, then $f(x) \in f(K_n)$ for all $n$ and so $f(K) \subset \bigcap f(K_n)$.

$\Leftarrow$
Let $y \in f(K_n)$ for all $n$. The set $f^{-1}(y) \bigcap K_n$ is a nonempty closes subset of $K_n$ and hence compact. Also they are decreasing and hence by Cantor's Intersection Theorem, $\bigcap (f^{-1}(y) \bigcap K_n) \neq \phi$. This means that there exist $x \in f^{-1}(y) \bigcap K_n$ for all $n$.

Is the solution correct. Does it have a better solution??

Comment: Judging by your tags, $Y$ is assumed to be a metric space? If so, then $\{y\}$ is indeed closed, and the rest of your proof follows nicely.

Answer (score 4):

As Jonathan Y. says, so long as $\{y\}$ is closed for each $y$ in your space - in particular, if your space is a metric space - then this is good.

On the other hand, without that assumption, the statement need not be true! Consider the topology on $\mathbb{N}$ where $X$ is open iff $X$ is a final segment of $\mathbb{N}$, that is, $a\in X, b>a\implies b\in X$. Then:

- The whole space, and each of its subsets, are compact.
- The constant function $x\mapsto 1$ is continuous (the preimage of any set is either empty or everything).

Now take $K_n=\{m: m>n\}$.

Comment: $ \cap _{n=1} ^{\infty} f(A_{n}) = 1 $, $ f(\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) = $, what is its value?

Comment: @JacobSchwartz The intersection $\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} K_{n}$ is the empty set, so its image is the empty set too. If you wish the intersection be non-empty then you can add to $X$ and each $K_n$ an isolated point $*$ which maps onto itself.