# $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ be continuous, $ A_{n+1} \subset A_{n}$ compact, show that $ f(\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) = \cap _{n=1} ^{\infty} f(A_{n})$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be topological space. Let $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ be continuous. If $ \{ A_{n} \} $ is a sequence of decreasing nonvoid and compact sets in $ X $, then show that

$$ f(\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) = \cap _{n=1} ^{\infty} f(A_{n}).$$

Since the intersection of all the $ A_{n} $ is contained in each $ A_{n} $ we have for any $ f $,
$$ f(\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) \subset \cap _{n=1} ^{\infty} f(A_{n}).$$

As observation, since $ \{ A_{n} \} $ is a sequence of decreasing nonvoid and compact sets in $ X $, $ \cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \neq \emptyset$ and hence $ f(\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) \neq \emptyset $.

For the other contention, let $ y \in \cap _{n=1} ^{\infty} f(A_{n}) $. Then $ y \in f(A_{n}) $ for all $ n $. Hence for all $ n $, $ y = f(x_{n}) $ with $ x_{n} \in A_{n} \subset X $, so $ \{ x_{n} \} $ is a sequence in $ X $, and then I get stuck. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/ In order to mark this question as answered. / In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148161/let-k-n-is-a-nonempty-compact-subset-of-x-and-that-k-n1-subset-k-n-for?rq=1)  question user8795 provided a proof for the case when the space $Y$ is $T_1$ and Noah Schweber in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1148584/71850) constructed a counterexample showing that otherwise the claim may be false.

Comment: In the example of Noah Schweber, $ \cap _{n=1} ^{\infty} f(A_{n}) = 1 $, $ f(\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) = $, what is your image?